# What's the difference between credential and certificate in SSL challenge?

Tags: ios, http, https

I'm working on a mobile APP, and SSL Pinning included.

1. Can anyone tell me the difference between credential and certificate in SSL challenge?
2. What's the difference between certificate chain and certificate?
3. Do I have to compare all the certificate?

Answer (score 0):

credential is anything that validates. like RSA key, password, API-keys,
and SSL so in this process a SSL based authentication is done for identification between two parties which will use a SSL certificate